# How to stop express sessionID generate a new one after stripe success payment redirect

Tags: node.js, express, session, stripe-payments

I am new in nodejs and express. I have spend a week on it and search a lot but nothing help.

It work fine when testing in localhost, after redirect from stripe successful payment, user keep the pervious sessionID.

But in production sometime when redirect successful payment from stripe, user's req.sessionID will generate a new one instead of using the pervious one. And it will cause some data lost.

But it not happen every payment, It only about 10% of payment will lost the sessionID.

Does anyone can help?   Big thanks

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  res.set('credentials', 'include');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});


app.use(express.urlencoded ({ extended : false}));
app.set('trust proxy', 1)

app.use(session({

    name :'randomName',
    store: store,
    secret: 'secret',
    proxy: true,
    cookie: {
      sameSite: 'lax',
      secure: true,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2 // 1 week
    },
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  }));
```

Here is the stripe api call.

```
router.post('/check_out_stripe', async (req,res,next)=>{

await req.session.save(async function(err) {
     
    
    var price = session_items.total_price - session_items.discount_pic - session_items.discount_score - session_items.discount_nine + session_items.shipping - session_items.shipping_discount -session_items.discount30 -session_items.discount_hk - session_items.discount_member- session_items.discount_code;
    price = Math.trunc(price) *100;

    if(price >0 && session_items && session_items.total_qty > 0 ){

           const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            line_items: [
              {
                price_data: {
                  
                  currency: 'hkd',
                  product_data: {
                    name: 'product',
                  },
                  unit_amount: price,
                },
                quantity: 1,
              },
            ],
            mode: 'payment',
            success_url: 'https://xxxx.com/order/order_confirm?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url: 'https://xxxx.com/order/payment_cancel',
            customer_email:email,
            billing_address_collection:"auto",
          
          });
          console.log("id :",session.id)
        
          res.json({ id: session.id });


    }
   
    })
})
```

font end calling

```
{
                fetch('/check_out_stripe', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: new URLSearchParams(params),
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
                })
                .then(function(session) {
                return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
                })
                .then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    alert(result.error.message);
                }
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                });
            }
```

Comment: What is `session` in the context of the code you've shared? I cannot see any specific Stripe API calls here, so you will need to provide some more details.

Comment: the session just store the data for shopping cart that user purchased.  Stripe work prefect but after redirect. Web session will sometime generate a new one instead of using the pervious one, so after confirm the payment i lost the data.   I try to provide the stripe call api if it could help..

Comment: You should implement a webhook and listen for `checkout.session.completed` events, instead of relying on your customers being redirected upon success.

Comment: OK. But an idea about user's sessionID change?